# Ввод текста SFML

Tags: c++, sfml

Как можно организовать ввод текста в окне SFML? Так чтобы при вводе отображался нужный шрифт, размер и тд.

Comment: если я не ошибаюсь, то встроенный штуки нет, можно просто при нажатии на кнопку букв и цифр, но это долго

Comment: Воспользуйтесь imgui - если не ошибаюсь, то под sfml он тоже есть

Comment: А что такое imgui?

Comment: ввод это ввод, это обработка событий от клавиатуры, причём всех, в том числе нажатий Shift, Alt и прочее. А вывод введённого с нужным шрифтом это второй вопрос. Правда там есть ещё для ввода `TextEvent`, попробуйте, но это штука ненадёжная, зависит от системы

Comment: Есть неплохая штука TGUI на базе SFML, но она сыроватая, автор занимается ей не очень плотно, но написана довольно красиво. https://tgui.eu.